# Dificuldades com slider e overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tenho uma estrutura me HTML e CSS para fazer um slider, deveria funcionar da seguinte forma: As imagens ficam uma ao lado da outra, porém, apenas uma aparece na tela, e como as imagens estarão uma ao lado da outra, o slider vai "rodando", encaixando a imagem na tela. Para isso, fiz o seguinte. Coloquei um `float:left;` para as imagens ficarem lado a lado, e isso somente funciona se o tamanho da width do elemento pai for grande o bastante para todas as imagens. Caso contrário, as imagens ficam uma embaixo da outra. Preciso fazer um slider como esse `http://cssslider.com/responsive-slider-2.html` ou este `http://globoesporte.globo.com/`, aonde as imagens estão uma ao lado da outra, e, conforme navegamos, elas se arrastam para esquerda e para direita, o meu problema é que eu nao consigo deixar as imagens alinhadas uma ao lado da outra. Só consigo quando aumento o width do elemento pai, e então não consigo "esconder" as imagens que saem da tela.

Aqui está o meu fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0gjoa6n8/1/

Se trocarem o `overflow` da `#slider` para `scroll`, verão que a imagem não fica lado a lado, e sim uma embaixo da outra. Como deixa-las lado a lado, porem, escondendo as que sairem da tela ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema estava na ul, que estava fazendo o `wrap`. Após adicionar `nowrap` no white space pelo css da ul, o conteúdo não foi mais "embrulhado", e ficou lado a lado.

Por padrão, os elementos quando ficam lado a lado tem um espaço em branco separando-os, e também por padrão, o html "embrulha" esse espaço, impedindo que as imagens neste caso fiquem lado a lado, pois a cada espaço em branco elas são embrulhadas e ficam uma embaixo da outra. Quando mandamos o espaço em branco não ser embrulhado com no-wrap, o problema deixou de ocorrer.

O fiddle atualizado: https://jsfiddle.net/0gjoa6n8/2/

Answer (score 1):

Não sei exatamente se e isso o que você deseja criar mas se for terá que fazer alguma mudanças em seu código, segue abaixo:

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        div#sliderContent > input{
            position:relative;
            top:12em;
            left:5em;
        }
        ul#slider{
            list-style:none;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            border:1px solid black;
            height:10em;
            width:15em;
        }
        ul#slider > li {
            display:inline;
        }
        li > label > img {
            width:15em;
            height:10em;   
            display:none;
        }
        input#slide1:checked ~ ul#slider>li>label[for=slide1]>img,
        input#slide2:checked ~ ul#slider>li>label[for=slide2]>img,
        input#slide3:checked ~ ul#slider>li>label[for=slide3]>img,
        input#slide4:checked ~ ul#slider>li>label[for=slide4]>img
        {
            display:block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sliderContent">
        <input type="radio" id="slide1" name="slide" checked />
        <input type="radio" id="slide2" name="slide" />
        <input type="radio" id="slide3" name="slide" />
        <input type="radio" id="slide4" name="slide" />
        <ul id="slider">
            <li>
                <label for="slide1">
                    <img src="http://b-i.forbesimg.com/geristengel/files/2013/05/i-ella-fashion-closet.jpg" />
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="slide2">
                    <img src="http://www.thefashionhall.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/hnjh.jpg" />
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="slide3">
                    <img src="http://melindahyder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Fashion.jpg" />
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="slide4">
                    <img src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/2bff0e00-cbe8-49e5-85d4-7e4c052df449/f097abfe-d3d6-42c5-9768-11616bc985e2.jpg" />
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Espero ter lhe ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas não era o que eu precisava, apenas precisava adicionar um `nowrap` na `ul`. Mas obrigado pela ajuda !